# How to add splitview to the sancha touch application and how to change the title (kitchen sink) on the title bar in xcode 4 iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have implemented a ***`sencha touch phone gap application on ipad.`***

using the kitchen sink application and its files.

It shows all the demo objects (list user interface buttons etc etc).

**`I need to add a split view as home page as per our application requirement on sencha touch appp.`**

And when i execute the application it displays title as "**Kitchen sink**" how should rename it as my application name

Comment: What do you mean by split view? Could you elaborate?

Comment: split view controoler just laike mail page a tableview /rootview on leftside, and the corresponding details view  on right side

Comment: Check the edited section of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `kitchen sink` app, there are two folders `phone` and `tablet`, each for specific devices.

In each of these folders, there's a file called `Main.js` which is the starting file of your application.

Hence, in that `Main.js`, change the `title` here ...

```
{
  id: 'mainNavigationBar',
  xtype : 'titlebar',
  docked: 'top',
  title : 'My Title',
  items: {
    xtype : 'button',
    .....
    .....
```

**EDIT :**

For your Split-view need, you can use hbox layout.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'TableView/Rootview goes here ...',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'Message Detail view goes here ....',
            flex: 2
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: how to i add a table view as root view in left side... and a view with a button as detaolsview in righ side of this split view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650697/sencha-touch-how-to-add-a-table-view-as-rootview-in-left-side-a-view-with-a-b